# Join two or more columns using UNPIVOT - SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please help me, I'm trying to move the columns to rows using `UNPIVOT`, but I need it, it doesn't work well for me. I need also the column name to be displayed in the row not just the value.

```
WITH ENCUESTA1

    AS  (
            SELECT
             Cod as 'Codigo' 
            ,Wifi as 'Wifi'
            ,EntreTvCable as 'Cable'

            FROM epha_rooms
        )
        

SELECT Codigo, Pregunta 
FROM ENCUESTA1
UNPIVOT
(
    Pregunta for col in ([Wifi], [Cable])
)un;
```

Result:

```
Codigo  Pregunta
---------------------
20      10
20      -7
21      10
21      4
22      10
22      10
23      10
```

I need to get this result:

```
Codigo  Pregunta    Value
-------------------------------
20      Wifi        10
20      Cable       -7
21      Wifi        10
21      Cable       4
22      Wifi        10
22      Cable       10
23      Wifi        10
```

Comment: Seriously? How about selecting the `col` column? With your requested columns names it would actually be `Value for Pregunta in ([Wifi], [Cable])`

Comment: Thanks, David,
It worked for me with your correction.
Now how could I add the VALUE column?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is not installed on my computer, but based [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15), I hope this code below helps you.

```
WITH ENCUESTA1

AS  (
        SELECT
         Cod as 'Codigo' 
        ,Wifi as 'Wifi'
        ,EntreTvCable as 'Cable'

        FROM epha_rooms
    )
    

SELECT Codigo, Pregunta, Value
FROM ENCUESTA1
UNPIVOT
(
    Value for Pregunta in ([Wifi], [Cable])
) un;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's what I need.